# Write to registry if parameter is specified

Tags: wix, registry, windows-installer

I have a setup that has an optional parameter which should be written to the registry is supplied. I know that i can write to the registry using this:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
    <Component Id="RegistryEntries" Guid="*">
        <RegistryKey Root="HKCU"
                     Key="Software\Microsoft\Test"
              Action="create">
            <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="[THEPARAMETER]"/>
        </RegistryKey>
    </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

But this will override the existing registry entry with an emtpy string, if the parameter is not specified!

I would like to know how to set the registry key ONLY if the parameter is specified. I have looked into custom actions and WriteRegistryValues, but I haven't found anything helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the condition like this

```
<Condition>(THEPARAMETER AND (NOT Installed))</Condition>
<RegistryValue Type="string" Value="[THEPARAMETER]"/>
```